# Run bash script file in Heroku programatically

Tags: bash, heroku, go

I have a web app written in Go and deployed on Heroku. Recently, I've implemented a new feature that needs to run a bash script file and retrieve its output. The command I'm using is:

```
out, err := exec.Command("bash", script_path, arg).Output()
```

Where script_path is the absolute path to the script. (which is built dynamically by using the caller filepath) And arg is an input to the script.

This command works fine in my local machine but not in Heroku:

> 18:51:40 http: panic serving 10.238.8.204:17763: exit status 127

ps: If I run the same command on "**heroku run bash**", it works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you fixed you issue?

Comment: Yes. It's working with the full path to bash executable:

out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", script_path, arg).Output()

Comment: Ok, so, I should do something wrong on my side! Thanks for the feedback and confirming that it is possible to do it!

Comment: Does your `script_path` looks like `/app/path/to/script.sh` ? It's annoying but I can't get it working whereas it works when using `heroku run bash`...

Comment: yes:

script_path := path.Join(".", "src", "ext", "dextenso.sh")

Comment: One more time, thanks a lot for your reply. Everything works like a charm now!

Comment: You're welcome! Some upvotes would be nice too xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a shell return code of `127` is to designate "Command not found".

You can see this behavior with this small example.

```
$ nonesuch
-bash: nonesuch: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

This sort of issue usually means you need to add

```
 /full/path/to/myscriptdir
```

to the `PATH` env var. i.e.

```
 export PATH="$PATH:/full/path/to/myscriptdir withSpaces"
```

There are several places this can be accomplished, but it depends on your organizations rules for such things.

To immediately resolve the problem, add to the `$HOME/.profile` file of the userID that runs Heroku OR there is likely a Heroku specific config file that it could be added to. (I don't have experience w Heroku).

It's interesting that this article [Heroku config files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) doesn't mention PATH variable.

---

As you have discovered, you can edit your code to include the full path directly, i.e.

```
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", path.Join(".", "src", "ext", "dextenso.sh"),
```

IHTH

Comment: Hi Shelter, you answer helped me to find the solution, but those steps with the PATH variable were not necessary. I just needed to specify the full path to the bash executable and to my script. Like this:  `out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", path.Join(".", "src", "ext", "dextenso.sh"), arg).Output()`. Could you edit your answer so I can mark it as the solution? thanks!

Comment: @marcelo : Hi, OK, I've done that. I'm glad it helped!